# Is making fun of marriage without thinking about its islamic part mockery of Islam

Tags: nikah, kufr

i had once heard a man say to his friend who was about to get married that "Marriage is the worst mistake a man can make" and then he proceeded to scare his friend with stories of how his life would be over after marriage, all in jest. I smiled at this. I'm sure that this man was not thinking of the part that marriage plays in Islam and was rather thinking of the social part.

Does that make a difference?

After this I thought about the marriage of the Prophet (peace be upon him) and how marriage is prescribed in Islam and I got worried and berated this man. But is this still considered mockery of the Prophet, all these things considered?

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE. Please consider taking our [tour] and checking our [help] to learn more about this site.

Comment: I'm trying hard to find a relation between this and that. Somebody may speak based on his own experience. And don't we say such meaningless things almost all the time?